# Skipped '***' -- An obstructing working copy was found

Tags: svn

I have originally checked out separate directories from the SVN repository, using `svn co path_to_repository/dir/ dir/ --depth=infinity`. Then I decided to check out the entire repository in the same path, but when I try to update it, it shows errors like `Skipped 'dir' -- An obstructing working copy was found`. Is there any way to tell it that it is part of the same repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you has no local modifications in `dir`, than it is simple:

1. Update `dir` to `HEAD`
2. Remove `dir/.svn` directory
3. Use `svn co ...` with `--force` option
4. revert possible  local modifications (possible if you not executed #1 or HEAD was changed after step#1) with `svn revert dir -R`

If you have local modifications, then svn keep them, but here is danger to mix you modifications with difference between dir BASE and checkout HEAD. If you not sure, save you work with `svn diff dir > my_work.patch` and restore it later.

Comment: Sadly dir/.svn no longer exists starting with v1.7, so this solution didn't work for me.